# Foundry writebacks - is it possible to restore an edited record to it's unedited version (BaseVersion)

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

Palantir-Foundry - We have a workflow that needs updates from the backing dataset of an object with a writeback to persist in the writeback, but this fails on rows that have previously been edited. Due to the "Edits-win" model the writeback it will always choose the edited version of the row, which makes sense. Short of re-architecting the entire app, I am looking into ways to take care of this by using the Foundry REST API.

Is it possible to revert an edited row in Foundry writebacks to the original unedited version? I found some API documentation in our instance for phonograph2 BaseVersion, but I have not been able to find/understand anything that would restore a row to BaseVersion. I would need to be able to do this from a functions repository using typescript, on certain events.

Answer (score 2):

One way to overwrite the edits with the values from a backing datasets is to build a transform off of the backing dataset that makes a new, identical dataset. Then you can use the new dataset as backing dataset for a new object.

Transform using a simple code repo:

```
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output

@transform_df(
    Output(".../static_guests"),
    source_df=Input("<backing dataset RID>"),
)
def compute(source_df):
    return source_df
```

You can then build up the ontology of a static object that will always equal the writeback dataset.

[image: Data Lineage graph showing how components fit]

Then create an action that will modify your edited object (in my example that is Test Guest) by reverting a value to equal a value in the static object type.

[image]

You can then use the Apply Action API to automatically apply this action to certain values on a schedule or based on a certain condition. Documentation for the API is [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/ontology-resources/actions/apply-action/).

Comment: Max you are a genius, I am not sure if you suggested this on my Issue ticket in platform as well, but this Apply Action is really what I was originally searching for. I was able to get a sample of this working in platform. I still need to think about it more but I think this API call could be a workaround for our current situation.